# How to link button?

Tags: html, material-design

Very simple question here, sorry if it's stupid.

I have the code here - but the button is not linking anywhere, can people help please?

```html
<div class="buttonwrapper">
  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/CSGOFlair">Twitter</a>
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think an `<a>` inside a `<button>` makes any sense?

Comment: It doesn't, I just tried it because adding href and target attributes directly to the button didn't work.

Comment: If you need to link to another page, use an `<a>` element. You don’t need the button. If you want it to look like a button, use CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple CSS button, use your button CSS to create one for `<a>` to make it a button look link.

```css
.buttonwrapper {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.button-link {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #4479BA;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #20538D;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-link:hover {
  background: #356094;
  border: solid 1px #2A4E77;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-link:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background: #2E5481;
  border: solid 1px #203E5F;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonwrapper">
  <a target="" class="button-link" href="https://twitter.com/CSGOFlair">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing wrong but don't worry.

```
<div class="buttonwrapper">
 <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/CSGOFlair">
 <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-rippleeffect">Twitter Button</button>
</a>

</div>
```

nest the button inside the a element and give it a name
more info about anchor element: [htmldog](http://htmldog.com/references/html/tags/a/)

Comment: you can remove the .buttonwrapper's div and give the anchor a display:block